# Is there a way to rescue an Azure VM with a changed IP?

Tags: azure, ip

I signed up for Azure, created my VMs for a farm and went about it as I normally would.  At the point of farm configuration where I set IP addresses, I didn't realize that Azure does not accept IPs unless they are Dynamic IP.

Now I know.

My question is, since now I can not login to the VM, is there a way to rescue it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown the VM from the web console. 
Delete the VM, but keep the associated disk.
Create a New VM, and use previously associated disk.
During the build process, the networking stack should get reconfigured, you should be able to access the VM again.

-john

Answer (score 0):

If you set up virtual networking, Azure will allow you to specify static internal IPs. That way you will always be able to at least VPN in to your virtual network and connect to your VMs from there.

As for "rescuing", you could download the VHD files for your VMs.

Comment: Ya, I created a Virtual Network with a range, and set my Network Adapter Ipv4 IP to one within that range.  Then it froze on me.  Do I need to setup a Virtual Network and a Local Network inside Azure?

Comment: You can't do it from the nic inside the client, it has to be done using one of the Azure SDKs (.net/python/powershell/rest/etc). AFAIK, It is not supported to set the NIC of a vm to a specific ip address.
http://windowsitpro.com/windows-azure/set-azure-vm-static-ip-address